# Windows 10 scheduled tasks are not running

Tags: windows-10, task-scheduler

I have created couple of tasks under Task scheduler (Win 10):

[image]

Unfortunatelly, the tasks do not run autmatically as scheduled. Their "Next run time" is changed as expected (each 10 or 5 minutes), but "Last Run Time" remain the same and nothing is done. There is even no record in history (15:23 was manual run half an hour ago):

[image]

In case I run the tasks manually, they work well. Conditions tab is empty for all of them. Any idea, what could be wrong?

Comment: Is your user logged in when the task runs? If not, did you change the setting so that it runs anyways?

Comment: Yep, user is logged in. Anyway, "Run whether user is logged on or not" option is checked and the password is saved. "Start the task only if the computer is idle for" option is not checked.

Comment: I just reinstalled OS and the issue is still here ....

Comment: Also, you may read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6568736/how-do-i-set-a-windows-scheduled-task-to-run-in-the-background

Answer (score 9):

I have a laptop and the same problem occured to me.

I resolved the issue DISABLING the option "Start the task only if the computer is on AC power" on the "Conditions" tab and "Power" group.

My laptop was indeed AC powered, but must be some kind of bug in this detection.

Comment: This helped me on a desktop PC with an uninterruptible power supply. When the diagnostics port of an UPS is attached to the PC, Windows seems to treat the machine like a laptop running on AC power.

Comment: oh my gawd FINALLY the right solution; I've been googling this for DAYS! I'm on a PC with regular connection and it didn't work until I disabled this checkbox. I NEVER WOULD'VE GUESSED it was the culprit (well, after reading this, I did notice MSI Afterburner had it unchecked, so I could've debugged better). Basically according to Microsoft desktop PC's are running on battery power

Answer (score 5):

I have same issue here. And found one workaround which may help someone to solve this.
If I set start date and time to be in future (near future, just 1 minute), task will be triggered and will repeat at specific interval.

Until user who start the task sign out!
If it signout, task won't start. Off-course Security options is set to Run whether user is logged on or not.

Comment: Finally I ended up with installing 3rd party scheduler and I am happy. I use Z-Cron, which can run as service.

Comment: This was my problem on Windows Server. Turned out when you are not remoting in it, you are not "logged in". Just set it to Run whether user is logged on or not.

Comment: Thank you very much, and +1. This was driving me mad - another MS crap. Seriously, are they crazy? Your solution was the only one which worked (Windows 10 Enterprise 1909).

Answer (score 3):

It appears that repeated tasks were broken by the Anniversary Update. Sad :/ There is no known work-around at this point other than to stop using the Task Scheduler and move to a third party solution.

More info [here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/d36db31f-7e96-48fc-9328-52795fa8d448/task-scheduler-no-longer-works-after-anniversary-update?forum=win10itprogeneral) - there are a few workarounds suggested but none that are usable. One is to run the task under the SYSTEM account, but this is no good for anyone requiring a specific AD user.

Answer (score 2):

I'm seeing the same thing on some servers running Server 2012 but it only seems to happen after the system is rebooted. The solution I've found is editing the trigger and changing the start time slightly. Once I've done that the task runs fine. Will have to see if the problem comes back after the next reboot.

Comment: I can confirm this works in similar scenarios I've encountered

Answer (score 1):

Please check your Trigger tab and open your trigger.  I had a trigger end up with the enabled box unchecked despite never unchecking it.  The main screen still showed enabled and ready for the task when this was unchecked and I had this exact behavior.

Answer (score 0):

This may be helpful for others in the future, but I had a scheduled task that I was running as myself, but escalated, to create command line Volume Shadow Copies. I eventually reconfigured it to run as SYSTEM and then it started running again.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.

Running on Windows Server 2008.

Tried all the solutions proposed here, and from other forum. Nothing works.

The only thing that worked for me, was to convert the BAT to EXE.

Then it run perfect.

Somehow, I dont know if it was an update from Windows or what, but from one minute to another, Taskman started to have this issue, and this was the only thing that made it work again

Hope it helps

Regards!